# Server side Google Play In App Billing receipt testing

Tags: google-play

We do validate the google play in app purchase receipt on our backend server.
For testing we do fake the receipts and test with them our system.

Is there a possibility to do a test purchase from the backend server to google's test server, to generate a receipt?
Or is there a possibility to get an fake receipt directly from google play?

For Android there are static responses for testing, maybe for backend server too.

It will be a better test then to fake the receipt by my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All purchases, including test purchases, **must be done using an Android application** (via a real device or an emulator). It happens because the purchase is executed by the Google Play Store app, and authenticated by the user.

About the server-side API, according to the [Google Play Developer API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/developer-api.html), you can use the [Subscriptions and In-App Purchases API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/developer-api.html#subscriptions_api_overview) to:

> [...] manage your app's catalog of in-app products and subscriptions. In
>   addition, with the Subscriptions and In-App Purchases API you can
>   quickly retrieve the details of any purchase using a standard GET
>   request.

So, after your purchase is completed (starting on the device), you can manage it's status, get details from the API and etc.

Comment: I was hoping we may have automatic acceptance tests without using a mobile device and fake purchases. But ok, thanks

Comment: So the only way to test the flow is actually make a payment from app and manage everything from backend?